# How OS detects USB Hard Disk when it's Connected

Tags: python, operating-system

How OS detects external Hard-Drive. I mean what procedure or system calls it makes to know about disk.
Is there any way to automatically determine if External HDD got connected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering the only question in your question.)

For Windows, you need to create a window and handle the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, specifically the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` event (which is sent automatically without having to register).

To do this from Python without creating a window, as far as I know the best you can do is to periodically test whether the root paths exist (once per second is probably sufficient, if you need to respond quicker than that Python is not going to work for you):

```
import os.path
for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    drive_mounted[letter] = os.path.exists(letter + ":")
```

---

(Answering the non-questions in your question.)

The operating system detects USB/eSATA devices because the USB/eSATA controller on the motherboard will raise an interrupt on the CPU. The OS detects this interrupt and asks the controller about the device, installs any drivers necessary, activates the drivers, identifies a mount point (drive letter) and plays a sound effect.

(None of this has anything to do with Python, so I assume it also has nothing to do with this question.)

Comment: That's great info Zooba, thanks. SO how to perform some task automatically when device connects to system, for example getting list of all media files and to check if those are there in my system ?

Comment: Also it would be great if you direct me something for Linux.

Comment: I don't use Linux, so I can't help beyond the platform-independent method I suggested above (`os.path.exists`). To do something when this happens, your program simply needs to be running all the time waiting for this event - then it can do anything when it happens. Alternatively, you could use your OS's auto-start functionality (if any) to let it run your program when a device is connected (though Python may not be suitable for this approach). Relevant keywords include "auto insert notification", "autoplay" and "autorun".

Comment: Thanks. OK, will google on keywords. But prior approch to check path all the time is not good. I'll do some research and post my findings.